# Google Voice Recognition on iOS

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

I would like to use the Google Voice Recognition / Speech API on my iOS app.

Someone have idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. But you have other speech recognition APIs developed for iOS like the following:

1. [Open Ears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)
2. [iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org/)

Comment: use it:https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Objective-C/Speech-REST-Nonstreaming