# How to add google speech recognition in app

Tags: iphone, ios, speech-recognition

I want to integrate Google speech recognition in my app but does not find much resource on this topic.

In [this tutorial](http://8byte8.com/blog/2012/07/voice-recognition-ios/) it says that its possible. But i have done some research in SO and i find only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517074/google-voice-recognition-on-ios) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition) Question/Answer which says its not possible so i am confuse what to do.

Does Google have documentation on speech recognition API? Should we able to use it in iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think google provides any Objective-C APIs. There's a speech-recognition API for google chrome (see [this](http://stiltsoft.com/blog/2013/05/google-chrome-how-to-use-the-web-speech-api/)), but you can't use it in iOS.

I also couldn't find anything in [google's developers site](https://developers.google.com/), so I suggest you to try other APIs for that.